# Answer link titles in user profiles deserves closed status too

Tags: script

### About

User profiles show post closed status on the "Questions" tabs, but not on the "Answers" tabs. As noted, partially by me, in [Should “duplicate” and “closed” attributes be added to the answer log in user profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401986/should-duplicate-and-closed-attributes-be-added-to-the-answer-log-in-user-pr) it's undesireable to have to go through every link on the "Answers" tab just to see which ones are closed. This script brings closed status to post titles.

It works on

- "Activity" ➝ "Summary" for both the "Answers" and "Reputation" areas.
  [image]
  <sup>Note: Even with lengthy titles the closed status will still show.</sup>
- "Activity" ➝ "Answer".
  [image]
- "Top posts" part of "Profile". Appending the status at the end of titles, like above.

#### How it works

It uses the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) to get post information.

If the remaining daily API quota is under 1500, it shows a notice:

[image]

#### Sites

Across the Stack Exchange network.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager in any major browser.
Tested with TamperMonkey using Opera.

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackAnswerClosedStatus) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackAnswerClosedStatus/StackAnswerClosedStatus.user.js) | [Uglified](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackAnswerClosedStatus/StackAnswerClosedStatus.ugly.user.js)

### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.